# `Model.plans.Count` threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to display a list of string objects as checkboxes. I have two projects, ASP.NET Core MVC app project and ASP.NET Core Web API both running on 5.0 NET Core. In the MVC project, I am calling the web API project where it will create a new list of objects. Then in my MVC project I did a project reference to call the controller in the view. When I run the application, the MVC will hit the line where it calls the API project. After storing the new created objects in the `GetPlan()` method in my API controller, I try to display those created objects as checkboxes in my MVC view. However, when I do so it says `Model.plans.Count` threw an exception of type `System.NullReferenceException`. Then looking further into it, it will only tell me:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

I do not understand why I it is returning null if the new objects were created already.

MVC project:

`Controller` where I am calling my API:

```
 public IActionResult SecIndex()
    {
        // call planapi
        var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result;
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Reached the Second Page View....");
        return View();
    }
```

then my API project:

`Model class for ViewPhoneNumberInput`:

```
  public class ViewPhoneNumberInput
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You did not enter your phone number! Please enter your phone number!")]
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Plans> plans { get; set; }
    }
```

My plans model class:

```
    public class Plans
    {
        public int PlanId { get; set; }
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
    }
```

`Controller` for api:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("AvailablePlans")]
        public ActionResult GetPlan()
        {

            var _model = new ViewPhoneNumberInput();
            _model.plans = new List<Plans>();

            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });


            var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_model.plans);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);


            return Ok(_model.plans);
        }
```

Above `_model.plans` will hold the values of the new objects created, so then I go to my MVC view project to call it so I can have it displayed but that is where it says that `Model.plans.Count` threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException`.

`View` for MVC project:

```
@model Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput


<h2>Second page</h2>




@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.plans.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" name="Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
        <label for="Model.plans[i].PlanId"> @Model.plans[i].PlanName </label> <br />
    }


    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.PhoneNumber)
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />

    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.PhoneNumber) </p>

}
```

**Is there a reason why it is telling me that and not actually holding the newly created values from the API controller?**

---

**When implementing the suggestion below, I am able to see a value for PhoneNumber but for Plans it shows null (when hovering over `phoneNumberInput` in the post SecIndex).**

My RetrievePlans():

```
        public async Task<List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>> RetrievePlans()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/plans/AvailablePlans");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

           var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>>(result);

            return json;
        }
```

My updated `SecIndex() with Post SecIndex()`:

```
        public IActionResult SecIndex()
        {
            // call planapi
            var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result;
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Reached the Second Page View....");
            return View(new Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput { plans = result });//So that you don't need to change the model in the view and the parameter type in the HttpPost Action.
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SecIndex(Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput phoneNumberInput)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "User successfully entered their phone number.");
                    return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex", "Final");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "User missed to enter their phone number");
                    throw new Exception("User did not enter a phone number in the textfield!");
                }
             
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Empty textfield!");
                return View(phoneNumberInput);
            }
        }
```

`SecIndex.cshtml`

```
@model Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput

<h2>Second page</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.plans.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
        <input hidden value="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
        <input hidden value="@Model.plans[i].PlanName" />

        <label for="Model.plans[i].PlanId"> @Model.plans[i].PlanName </label>
        <br />
    }


    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.PhoneNumber)
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />

    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.PhoneNumber) </p>

}
<script>
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                this.nextElementSibling.name = "plans["+count+"].PlanId";
                this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.name = "plans[" + count + "].PlanName";
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My API GetPlan controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("AvailablePlans")]
        public List<Plans> GetPlan()
        {

            var _model = new ViewPhoneNumberInput();
            _model.plans = new List<Plans>();

            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });


            var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_model.plans);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);


            return _model.plans;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  working demo:

api method:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("AvailablePlans")]
        public List<Plan.API.Models.Plans> GetPlan()
        {

            var _model = new ViewPhoneNumberInput();
            _model.plans = new List<Plans>();

            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
            _model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });


            var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_model.plans);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);


            return _model.plans;
        }
```

controller action:

```
public IActionResult SecIndex()
    {
        // call planapi
        var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result;
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Reached the Second Page View....");
        return View(new ViewPhoneNumberInput {  plans=result});//So that you don't need to change the model in the view and the parameter type in the HttpPost Action.
    }
```

View:

```
@model Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput


<h2>Second page</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.plans.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
        <input hidden value="@Model.plans[i].PlanId"/>
        <input hidden value="@Model.plans[i].PlanName" />

        <label for="Model.plans[i].PlanId"> @Model.plans[i].PlanName </label>
        <br />
    }


    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.PhoneNumber)
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />

    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.PhoneNumber) </p>

}
<script>
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                this.nextElementSibling.name = "plans["+count+"].PlanId";
                this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.name = "plans[" + count + "].PlanName";
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! When attempting to implement your solution, I ran into a problem at the return line of `SecIndex()`. Where it has ` return View(new Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput { plans = result });` it has a redline under result saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>`.  I copied your solution exactly too, but the only difference I made was to add the reference in the return line of `SecIndex()` and remove the reference on the signature of `GetPlan()` since `ViewPhoneNumberInput` exists in API

Comment: Did you use the the `RetrievePlan()` that was implemented in the post or did you modify that?

Comment: Please let me know if I implemented `RetrievePlan()` correctly because when I hover over `phoneNumberInput` I am able to see the value in `PhoneNumber` but `Plans` is null for me. Please check the updated section in the post

Comment: RetrievePlan() returns `List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>`,so it is impossible to get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Plan.API.Models.ViewPhoneNumberInput' to System.Collections.Generic.List<Plan.API.Models.Plans>` when using `return View(new ViewPhoneNumberInput {  plans=result});`

Answer (score 1):

@MarCo issue is you are not passing your modal

```
return View(result);
```

Comment: I didn't pass it since I do not have a different view for result. If I do `return View(result);` in my `SecIndex()` it will tell me `InvalidOperationException: The view '[{"planId":1,"planName":"Internet"},{"planId":2,"planName":"TV & Streaming"},{"planId":3,"planName":"Mobile"},{"planId":4,"planName":"Home Security"},{"planId":5,"planName":"Home Phone"}]' was not found. The following locations were searched:` and gives me places it checked

Comment: @MarkCo when you use this line
return View(result);
the view name will be decided by the ActionName which is SecIndex and the result passed to view SecIndex.

Comment: I see, so why is it returning that if in the controller I did `return Ok(_model.plans);` which would hold the new values?

Comment: @MarkCo return Ok(_model.Plans) means return data as plaintext with status code 200 and mostly used at API side. 
return view(result) means we are returning a view and passing result as a model which we will use inside our view.

Comment: So I would have to create a new view specifically for the `result`?

Comment: I posted a screenshot of what happens when I do `return View(result)` if it helps

Comment: @MarkCo I think your data is not parsed. 
var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result; 
result is string? can you verify that

Comment: Yes, when I hover over result it says its a string

Comment: @MarkCo That is the issue you have to parse your data into the appropriate model.

Comment: Yeah it displays this as a string: [{"planId":1,"planName":"Internet"},{"planId":2,"planName":"TV & Streaming"},{"planId":3,"planName":"Mobile"},{"planId":4,"planName":"Home Security"},{"planId":5,"planName":"Home Phone"}]

Comment: @MarkCo there are few ways for parsing data but the most used method is
1- Install pakage Newtonsoft.Json on MVC side
than after this line

var result = _planServiceClient.RetrievePlans().Result;
var plans = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Plans>>(result);
return View(plans);

Comment: So I would need to parse result as int and string (model class Plans)?

Comment: @MarkCo you can also use this line inside your RetrievePlans() method like
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Plans>>(json);

Comment: I just did the first way, but what would the variable (json) represent since there isn't a json in the RetrievePlans()? I tried result but it does not like that

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of RetrievePlans() where you made changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235677/discussion-between-markco-and-ali-ahmad).